# How to get data returned by tasks in asyncio.wait()?

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio

Hey guys so I have this function in python that is async and after finishing returns a value but this function is added as a task as many times as there is items in a certain list the thing is I dont seem to be able to get the values returned from such functions after `asyncio.wait()` finishes running.

The code (I removed most of the bloat so this is a simplified code):

```
async def transcribe(s3_path: str, file_name: str):
    for attempt in range(MAX_WAIT_ATTEMPTS):
        
        # Do some stuff

        await asyncio.sleep(WAIT_TIME)

    return "value 1", "value 2"

async def transcribe_all_videos(videos_list: List[str], user_id: str):
    tasks = []
    for video in videos_list:
        tasks.append(
            asyncio.get_event_loop().create_task(transcribe("some path", "some video"))
        )

    result = await asyncio.wait(tasks)
    
    # Extract result return data

    return result
```

What I tried:

- I tried running `result[0].result()`
- `result.result()`

None of those seem to work and the error is always in the lines of `'tuple' object has no attribute 'result'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`asyncio.wait`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.wait) returns done and pending tasks. So iterate over *done* tasks and use the `.result()` method:

```py
import asyncio


async def transcribe(s3_path: str, file_name: str):
    await asyncio.sleep(1)
    return "value 1", "value 2"


async def transcribe_all_videos(videos_list, user_id):
    tasks = []
    for video in videos_list:
        tasks.append(
            asyncio.get_event_loop().create_task(
                transcribe("some path", "some video")
            )
        )

    done, pending = await asyncio.wait(tasks)

    for r in done:
        print(r.result())


asyncio.run(transcribe_all_videos(["xxx"], 1))
```

Prints:

```py
('value 1', 'value 2')
```

Comment: Quick question, is it possible to wait for all items to be done? Doesn't the wait implicitly only return when they all finish?

Comment: @DeadSec `asyncio.wait` has third parameter with default value `return_when=ALL_COMPLETED`. So it returns when all tasks complete.